# Google App Script (Spreadsheet) - Calculate Cell Values based on Color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to calculate the values of cells on a row x based on the color of the cell on the same column but on row y.

IE: 
If B3, D3 and E3 are blue.
Then SUM the values of B4, D4 and E4.

My Current Attempt (Quite Poor):

```
function sumWhereBackgroundColorElseWhereIs(color, colorRange, valueRange) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var colorRange = sheet.getRange(colorRange);
  var valueRange = sheet.getRange(valueRange);

  var total = 0;

  for (var i = 1; i <= colorRange.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= colorRange.getNumColumns(); j++) {

      var cell = range.getCell(i, j);

      if(cell.getBackgroundColor() == color) {

      }
    }
  }
  for 
  var valueCell = range.getCell(i, j);
  total += parseFloat(cell.getValue());
  return total;
}
```

Comment: Explain in detail whats not working with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how I accomplished this.

```
function setForegroundColor() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(""); 
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange(3, 2, 1, 10); //getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) (change the last value to increase the columns serviced)
  for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    cell = range.getCell(1,i);
    color = cell.getBackground();
    cell.setFontColor(color);
  }
}

function calculateBLUFORManPower() {
 var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(""); 
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
  var x = 0;
  var range = sheet.getRange(3, 2, 1, 10); //getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) (change the last value to increase the columns serviced)
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A17");
  var BLUFORColor = cell.getBackground();
  for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    cell = range.getCell(1,i);
    color = cell.getBackground();
    if (color == BLUFORColor && cell.getValue != "") {
      x = x + cell.getValue();
    }
  }
  var cell = sheet.getRange("B19");
  cell.setValue(x);
}

function calculateBLUFORUnits() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(""); 
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
  var x = 0;
  var range = sheet.getRange(3, 2, 1, 10); //getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) (change the last value to increase the columns serviced)
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A17");
  var BLUFORColor = cell.getBackground();
  for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    cell = range.getCell(1,i);
    color = cell.getBackground();
    if (color == BLUFORColor) {
      x += 1;
    }
  }
  var cell = sheet.getRange("B18");
  cell.setValue(x);
}

function calculateOPFORManPower() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(""); 
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
  var x = 0;
  var range = sheet.getRange(3, 2, 1, 10); //getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) (change the last value to increase the columns serviced)
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A20");
  var OPFORColor = cell.getBackground();
  for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    cell = range.getCell(1,i);
    color = cell.getBackground();
    if (color == OPFORColor && cell.getValue != "") {
      x = x + cell.getValue();
    }
  }
  var cell = sheet.getRange("B22");
  cell.setValue(x);
}

function calculateOPFORUnits() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(""); 
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
  var x = 0;
  var range = sheet.getRange(3, 2, 1, 10); //getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) (change the last value to increase the columns serviced)
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A20");
  var OPFORColor = cell.getBackground();
  for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    cell = range.getCell(1,i);
    color = cell.getBackground();
    if (color == OPFORColor) {
      x += 1;
    }
  }
  var cell = sheet.getRange("B21");
  cell.setValue(x);
}

function OPFOR() {
  calculateOPFORUnits();
  calculateOPFORManPower();
}

function BLUFOR() {
  calculateBLUFORUnits();
  calculateBLUFORManPower();
}

function ALL(){
  setForegroundColor();
  BLUFOR();
  OPFOR();
}
```

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/fBwLgFU7)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you are trying to do, as you're trying to do it, with a custom function.

The range argument in a custom function sends an array of values, from the range, to the function and not the range object itself.

Therefore, in your code, colorRange would contain the values in the range and not the range itself so there would be no way to determine the backgound colors.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the range to call the background colours the way you are doing it.

There are workarounds as posted [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58179)

Also You have to type the colour codes instead of the names.

In your case you would have to type the custom function either like this

```
=sumWhereBackgroundColorElseWhereIs("#0000ff","B3:F3","B4:F4")
```

Or like this

```
 =sumWhereBackgroundColorElseWhereIs("#0000ff",CELL("address",B3)&":"&CELL("address",F3),CELL("address",B4)&":"&CELL("address",F4))
```

And your script would look like this

```
 function sumWhereBackgroundColorElseWhereIs(color, ColorRange, ValueRange) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var colorRange = sheet.getRange(ColorRange);
  var valueRange = sheet.getRange(ValueRange);
  var firstColumn = colorRange.getColumn();
  var lastColumn = colorRange.getLastColumn();
  var valueRangeRow = valueRange.getRow();
  var backgrounds = colorRange.getBackgrounds();
  backgrounds = backgrounds.toString().split(",");

  var total = 0;

  for (var i = firstColumn; i <= lastColumn; i++) {
    var ref = i - firstColumn;
    if (backgrounds[ref] === color) {
      total = total + Number(sheet.getRange(valueRangeRow, i).getValue());
    }
  }

  return total; 
}
```